# Android Multi Window doesn't work when android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, landscape-portrait

as the title says, when the next line of code

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

is entered in my Manifest file then when I start my app and, for example, dragging the gallery app to it then its not activating the multi window feature which splits the screen... but just replace my app with the gallery app, meaning the gallery app takes all the screen instead of taking only half of it.

If I first open the gallery app and then dragging my app then its working fine.
Also if I remove the above line of code then its working fine.

This is my Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.samsunmultiwindowstest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.samsunmultiwindowstest.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER"/>                                          
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 

    <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"> </uses-library>
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />        
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />

</application>
```

how can I force portrait mode and get the multi window feature?

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: Does your phone supports `Multi-Window Feature`?? Which phone your are using?

Comment: Yes my phone support it, if it weren't then nothing would work.but its working when this line is ommited from the manifest:  android: screenOrientation="portrait"  and even if not ommited then as i explaing when i first open the gallery app and then dragging my app its works anyway but the other way doesn't work.

Comment: My phone is Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Link [Screen Orientation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). It will help you understand different kinds of screen orientation. Also check [this](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/howtoguide/N0000004/8829/62396) and [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smartphones/how-to-use-multi-window-with-your-samsung-galaxy-s-iii/). will help you to enable multi window feature

Comment: You can also set the orientation for particular activity programmatically. as `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: I did all that in the past and verfy it now but its still doesn't work, i think its has to do with the code and not the phone settings. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Also, after the screen is splitting then how you can make your app to be scrollable? because now I see my app smaller by half but i cant go down/up and see other things in my layout/view?

Comment: Have you used `ScrollView`??

Comment: No, its just a regular layout. I thought that if multi window feature is making my app view smaller by half then it will let me scroll up or down so i can go to whatever place in that layout. for example if its a login layout and my setting are at the top and the ok button at the bottom then i could reach both of them ,not?

Comment: You need to use scroll view. Check [ScrollView Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/)

Comment: Its sounds crazy! you mean that if someone wants his App to support this multi window feature and that it will look and act good he needs that all his layouts will be wrapped by scrollview so when the screen will split then he could scroll up/down???

Answer (score 0):

I simply took out the size settings to solve my multiWindow issues.

IE: Remove these lines altogether.

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
```